# How to make DropdownButton list to appear below the Item shown in flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton, dropdownlistview

I am getting the list in `DropdownButton` above the item shown. But my requirement is the list to start from below the Selected Item.i.e. **from below the textBox where selected item is showing.**

[image]

means the list will appear from below the Selected Item ,,

Comment: perhaps increase the width ?

Comment: Can you share an image or some more hint which could describe your requirement more clearly

Comment: dropdown list will appear from below the item..

Comment: You mean the list animation?

Comment: I have edited the post..and added picture link